# Changes in node_modules does not reflect to React (possibly bundle.js not getting updated)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle, node-modules

I'm using a library in my react application that I want to make a few changes to. I know how to use patch-package so the persistence of the changes will not be a problem, but I can't fiddle with the code for developing purposes because my changes are not reflected when I run react.

Here's an example of the folder structure in the library;

```
x-library
-dist
--components
---index.js
--bundle.js
```

When I make changes in index.js, it does not reflect to react. It does so when I make the same change in bundle.js, so I'm guessing index.js gets ignored somehow? I don't know how webpack/bundle.js works very well but from what I understand, bundle.js is a compressed version of the code that the browser uses. Is it that my changes in code does not get compressed again for a new version of bundle.js and uses the old one?

Here's the library's webpack.config.js;

```
var path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'Wheel',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|dist)/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  externals: {
    react: {
      commonjs: 'react',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      amd: 'React',
      root: 'React',
    },
    'react-dom': {
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'ReactDOM',
      root: 'ReactDOM',
    },
  },
}
```

And here's the library's package.json;

```
{
  "name": "react-custom-roulette",
  "version": "1.1.8",
  "description": "Customizable React roulette wheel with spinning animation",
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/effectussoftware/react-custom-roulette"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "custom",
    "roulette",
    "spinning",
    "wheel",
    "fortune",
    "prize"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.9",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.9.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^11.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.16.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript-prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "8.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.2.2",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start-server": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack && tsc && cp -R ./src/assets ./dist",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "coverage": "CI=true npm test -- --env=jsdom --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}",
    "link-react": "cd example/node_modules/react && npm link && cd ../react-dom && npm link && cd ../../.. && npm link react react-dom"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "yarn format && yarn lint"
    }
  },
  "jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "src/serviceWorker.ts"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```